# When we want to add an example just to be clearer, what kinds of sentences should we use?

Tags: sentence-usage, conversation

This is the original text:

> Each cardiac muscle fiber contains a single nucleus and is **striated**, or **striped**, because it appears to have light and dark bands when seen through a microscope.

Suppose, just to be clear I want to give an example before saying this, these are my examples:

> 1. 'a black and white **striped** shirt'
> 2. 'the **black and yellow banding** of bees and wasps'

I want something like this:

> Just to be clear let me give you an example: consider a black & white **striped shirt**. Well, cardiac muscle tissue has got a structure just like this.
>
> Each cardiac muscle fiber contains a single nucleus and is striated, or **striped**, because it appears to have light and dark bands when seen through a microscope.

● Are there any better ways to connect the above-mentioned examples with the original context?

Comment: For what it is worth, I think that what you have said is sufficient without any need for these examples. I would especially not include descriptions such as 'black and white' or 'black and yellow', as an ordinary H&E stain will not show such colours.

Comment: I do not understand your question, "any ways to connect". What are you trying to do there? You're explaining what **striated** means by giving a synonym, **striped**, but beforehand you want to explain what **striped** means by giving an example of its use and yet another synonym, **banding**??

Comment: ***is** striated ... **because**  it appears* is unclear.

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo I want something like this:
"Just to be clear let me give you an example: consider a black & white striped shirt. Well, cardiac muscle tissue has got a structure just like this.

Each cardiac muscle fiber contains a single nucleus and is striated, or striped, because it appears to have light and dark bands when seen through a microscope."

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo [Each cardiac muscle fiber contains a single nucleus and is striated, or striped, because it appears to have light and dark bands when seen through a microscope.](http://www.innerbody.com/image_musc01/musc71.html#continued) The first paragraph after the preface and pictures.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So it seems you're looking for a rhetorical strategy.

> We all know what stripes are: striped shirts, the banding on wasps and
>   bees, and so forth. Under the microscope, cardiac muscle fiber appears
>   to have stripes. The scientific word for such stripes is
>   **striations**. The muscle fiber is said to be **striated**.

Comment: I really appreciate all the hard work you’ve done to help us.

Comment: I have a question. "The banding **on** wasps and bees" or "The banding **of** wasps and bees"?

Comment: **on** refers elliptically to the locative presence (on the abdomen) and **of** refers to the stripes *as attribute*.